# Search through subfolders to find different files with the same extension

Tags: batch-file

In a directory structure with a lot of subdirectories, how can I search and find subdirectories containing more than one file with the same extension, and write them with path to a text file?

I want to run the batch-file in `C:\test` directory, and the result should be a `.txt` file in `C:\test`, with the full path of each of those subdirectories, e.g. `c:\test\ghi\`

Comment: `dir /s /a-d "startdirectoryname\*.ext1" >reportfilename` - `"startdirectoryname\*.ext1"` can be repeated for other extensions.

Comment: I suggest that, in order to make your question perfectly clear, you [edit] your question and post a sample directory tree structure as well as the contents of the text file that you expect your batch script to write for that sample directory tree.